# All Textgenrnn configuration options

Tags: tensorflow

In the Google Colab there are these configuration options for making a Textgenrnn model:

```
model_cfg = {
    # set to True if want to train a word-level model (requires more data and smaller max_length)
    'word_level': False,
    # number of LSTM cells of each layer (128/256 recommended)
    'rnn_size': 128,
    'rnn_layers': 3,   # number of LSTM layers (>=2 recommended)
    # consider text both forwards and backward, can give a training boost
    'rnn_bidirectional': False,
    # number of tokens to consider before predicting the next (20-40 for characters, 5-10 for words recommended)
    'max_length': 30,
    # maximum number of words to model; the rest will be ignored (word-level model only)
    'max_words': 10000,
}

train_cfg = {
    # set to True if each text has its own line in the source file
    'line_delimited': False,
    'num_epochs': 1,   # set higher to train the model for longer
    'gen_epochs': 1,   # generates sample text from model after given number of epochs
    # proportion of input data to train on: setting < 1.0 limits model from learning perfectly
    'train_size': 0.8,
    'dropout': 0.0,   # ignore a random proportion of source tokens each epoch, allowing model to generalize better
    # If train__size < 1.0, test on holdout dataset; will make overall training slower
    'validation': False,
    'is_csv': False   # set to True if file is a CSV exported from Excel/BigQuery/pandas
}
```

I was wondering, is there any reference/documentation to all possible configurations you could have for a model?
Thank,
Binkie